# Why this array permutation(duplicate) does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var permuteUnique = function(nums) {
  var res = [];
  if (nums.length == 0 || nums == null) return res;
  var used = [];
  var list = [];
  nums.sort();
  dfs(nums, used, list, res);
  return res;
};

function dfs(nums, used, list, res) {
  if (list.length == nums.length) {
    res.push(list.slice());
    return;
  }
  console.log(res, list);

  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (used[i]) continue;
    if (i > 0 && nums[i] === nums[i - 1] && !used[i]) continue;
    used[i] = true;
    list.push(nums[i]);
    dfs(nums, used, list.slice(), res);
    used[i] = false;
    list.pop();

  }
}

console.log(permuteUnique([1,1,2]));
```

after running, 
when input is `[1,1,2]`. the result always returns `[]`. The correct answer should be `[[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,1]]`.
Can someone help have a look at? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should also provide the output of your debugging attempts.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: He did provide that, read the paragraph below the code.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with: you are not reassigning the variable `res` in the function `permuteUnique`.

```
var permuteUnique = function(nums) {
    var res = []; // var res is assigned

    if (nums.length == 0 || nums == null) return res;

    var used = [];
    var list = [];
    nums.sort();
    dfs(nums, used, list, res);
    return res; // you never reassigned res, so it remains []
};
```

The result of `permuteUnique(whateverArgumentYouPass)` will, regardless of the passed argument, always be `[]`. You might want to read more about the basics of functions and return values [here](http://javascript.info/function-basics).

Besides, inside `permuteUnique` you call `dfs(nums, used, list, res);` but you never capture the return value. If you do the computations for finding the permutations there, you should return the computed values and assign it to a variable (in this case res). This would also not work in your code, because your function `dfs` will always return `undefined`.

There are also a couple of other things not working, but I'd first focus on above-mentioned points.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not need return value. It just modifies the **res**.